# solving a differential equation which is separable and exact at the same time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

as the title expresses, is there an easy way to solve a differential equation which is both separable and exact at the same time? To be more specific, I have an equation as: 
$$ f_1(x)f_2(y)dx+f_3(x)f_4(y)dy=0$$
which is also an exact differential equation as:
$$M(x,y)=f_1(x)f_2(y)$$
$$N(x,y)=f_3(x)f_4(y)$$
$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$$
I hope this is not a trivial question. I looked up the net but I could not find something similar. 
Thanks for the answers!

Comment: What do you consider to be an "easy way"? You can use either the exact, or separable method to solve the equation. It depends on the function forms as to which method is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is by separable method. Of course it could be both separable and exact, but if you cand it separables why expend time doing it by exact method?

I mean, you can do it but only to have another procedure and check the answer. Also can convert it into a Linear form but that depends on what $\ f_1(x)\ $, $\ f_2(y)\ $, $\ f_3(x)$, $\ f_4(y)\ $

$$y'=-\frac{f_1(x)f_2(y)}{f_3(x)f_4(y)}$$

$$y'=f_5(x)f_6(y)$$

From the last step depends if can be simplified to an Homogeneous Form, or Linear but as you can see also still is separable.

Example:

$$3x^2 y^3 dx+3x^3 y^2 dy=0\\ M_y=9x^2 y^2 \\ N_x=9x^2 y^2 $$

$$y'=-\frac{y}{x}$$

The ODE can be solved by Separable, Homogeneous, Linear, Exact

I think that's what you want.